"Two-stage sampling": appropriate name?
Assume that it is desired to estimate the probability $p$ of occurrence of some characteristic in a given population, based on binary observations. For example, the probability of a person having some genetic condition is estimated by selecting a sample of people, and applying to each of them a test to detect the presence or absence of that condition.
As is well known, the sample size required to obtain a reliable estimation of $p$ depends precisely on $p$ (smaller $p$ requires a larger sample size). Consider the following sampling scheme (A):

An initial sample is taken (either with a predefined size or using a sequential stopping rule), from which a rough estimate of $p$ is obtained. This estimate is used for selecting an appropriate size for a second sampling stage, from which the final estimate of $p$ is obtained.

In a paper I am writing, I would like to call (A) a two-stage sampling scheme (it has two stages, and I think the name is clear and descriptive). However, the name "two-stage sampling", or "two-stage cluster sampling", is applied to a form of cluster sampling (B):

Given a population of clusters, each of which contains a number of individuals, the first stage selects a subset of clusters, and the second stage selects some individuals within each cluster.

On the other hand, I have seen the qualifier "two-stage" used in other contexts, not just cluster sampling, for example: "auto-regressive two-stage model", "two-stage least squares", "two-stage PCA".
My questions:

Would it be acceptable to call (A) two-stage sampling? (The specific method will of course be described in the paper). Or would it be confusing, given that the name is/may be applied to (B)?
How common is the use of the name "two-stage sampling" to mean (B)? Is (B) most commonly called "two-stage cluster sampling"? (which would clear the way for my intended use of the name)
Is there some other, well established name for (A)?


The first of these samples is called a "pilot sample", which is a standard method of obtaining information for the purposes of sample size determination for a larger subsequent sample (see e.g., Browne 1995, Friede and Kieser 2006, O'Neill 2022).  You could call this overall sampling procedure "two-stage sampling" if you want to (since a pilot sample plus a subsequent sample is indeed two stages$^\dagger$) but it is typical just to describe the use of a pilot sample directly, with something like the following:

We estimate $p$ using the combination of an initial pilot sample (to determine an adequate sample size) combined with a subsequent larger sample (based on those sample size calculations).  ...

If you want to call it a two-stage sample, just make sure you also mention that the first stage is a pilot sample:

We estimate $p$ using a two-stage sampling method composed of an initial pilot sample (to determine an adequate sample size) combined with a subsequent larger sample (based on those sample size calculations).  ...


$^\dagger$ Don't worry about confusion with two-stage cluster sampling, since that ought to be described as "two-stage cluster sampling".  It is not the only method of sampling that involves two stages.

Thank you! (I also just found your paper on politically correct language, which I think I am going to enjoy) :-)

I will answer myself. After some searching, it seems like the qualifier "two-stage" has been used  in the technical literature for approaches similar to what I described as (A). So I think I can safely call it "two-stage sampling". Some examples I have found:

"On two fundamental problems of sequential estimation", Ghosh et al.: "The idea of a two-stage procedure goes essentially back to the late Professor P. C. Mahalanobis (1940). He suggested the idea of a pilot sample followed by the sample proper in connection with a sample survey of acreage under Jute in Bengal".

"Two-Stage and Sequential Unbiased Estimation of N in Binomial Trials, when the Probability of Success p is Unknown", Malinovsky et al.: they use two stages of sampling "in parallel", rather than "in cascade" as in my description, but otherwise the idea is similar, and unrelated to cluster sampling.

`"Two-stage and sequential sampling for estimation and testing with prescribed precision", S. Zacks: the approach is somewhat similar to what I described as (A). The first stage is also called a "pilot study" in this paper.


